# Screencapture keeps dedicated graphics active

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, graphics, screen-capture

When I use the screencapture tool on it turns on my dedicated graphics (Radeon Pro 560X) and when I finish the system doesn't switch to Intel graphics and consume my battery faster.Any idea how to make it stop?[image]

Comment: Do you use a button that's just next to that what get's open when you want to take a screenshot?

Comment: Same issue here. But when I used dropbox integration for screenshots uploading it did not activate Radeon (though it did not show screenshot editing window)